# LWC Java Script Error!

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

In the below code i am getting the below error, please help me out for compilation.

Code :

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class publicMethodChild extends LightningElement {
    @track value = ['red'];

    options = [
        { label: 'Red Marker', value: 'red' },
        { label: 'Blue Marker', value: 'blue' },
        { label: 'Green Marker', value: 'green' },
        { label: 'Black Marker', value: 'black' },
    ];

    @api
    selectCheckbox(checkboxValue){
       Const selectedCheckBox = this.options.find( checkbox =>{
            return checkBoxValue === checkbox.value;
        })

        if(selectedCheckBox){
            this.value = selectedCheckBox;
            return "Successfully checked";
        }
        return "No CheckBox found";

    }



}
```

Error :
{`LWC1007: c:\Users\ABHIJEET KUMAR\LWCSession\publicMethodChild.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (15:13)lwc`}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is **CaSe sEnSiTiVe**.

Its not `Const`, its [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

```
const selectedCheckBox = this.options.find( checkbox =>{
```

Comment: Thnaks :)  i am new to Java Script and LWC